# Function timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, function

I'm trying to write a code that adds a class to a div for a limited time, and then removes it.
I tried using javascript's setTimeout, and jQuery's delay, but nothing works.
The element is SET but never REMOVED.

Here's the come I came up with:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(".button").click(handler);
}

function handler() {
    $(this).addClass("onclick");
    setTimeout(function() { $(this).removeClass("onclick"); }, 3000); // JS's setTimeout

    $(this).addClass("onclick").delay(3000).removeClass("onclick"); // jQuery's delay
}
```

I don't get what's wrong... I even tried writing a second handler for the setTimeout function.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: One function's `this` is another function's `global object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `this` is different within the function you're passing to `setTimeout` than it is outside it. The usual fix is to use the closure by creating a variable to hold it, and using the variable instead:

```
function handler() {
    var $elm = $(this);

    $elm.addClass("onclick");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $elm.removeClass("onclick");
    }, 3000);
}
```

There I've also use the var to cache the result of `$(this)` because there's no point in doing it more than once.

More background:

In JavaScript, unlike some languages that look similar, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*. When you use `setTimeout`, the way the function gets called will make `this` be the global object (`window`, on browsers), so that's why `$(this).removeClass(...)` wasn't working.

More on `this` if you're interested:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the setTimeout call does not refer to the clicked element.

Change it to this:

```
function handler() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.addClass("onclick");
    setTimeout(function() { t.removeClass("onclick"); }, 3000);
}
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/5vakN/

Reference for how `this` works in javascript - http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this